# Printer is 'unreachable', all jobs are processing

Tags: printer

just decided to try and set up my Epson XP 225 printer on Manjaro after months of using printing services as I was too lazy to set it up. I installed the Epson driver from the AUR, and it installed smoothly. With some searching around I managed to add my printer (I am using it over USB, can't be bothered with wifi or Bluetooth setups) and managed to use the online localhost tool manual to enable my printer. I used to get these errors:

```
==> /var/log/cups/error_log <==
W [13/Jul/2023:02:54:55 +0200] [Job 2] The printer is unreachable at this time.
W [13/Jul/2023:02:55:26 +0200] [Job 2] The printer is unreachable at this time.
W [13/Jul/2023:02:55:58 +0200] [Job 2] The printer is unreachable at this time.
W [13/Jul/2023:02:56:31 +0200] [Job 2] The printer is unreachable at this time.
W [13/Jul/2023:02:57:06 +0200] [Job 2] The printer is unreachable at this time.
E [13/Jul/2023:02:57:15 +0200] [Client 384] pam_authenticate() returned 7 (Authentication failure)
E [13/Jul/2023:03:01:03 +0200] [Client 396] pam_authenticate() returned 10 (User not known to the underlying authentication module)
E [13/Jul/2023:03:01:20 +0200] [Client 398] pam_authenticate() returned 10 (User not known to the underlying authentication module)
W [13/Jul/2023:03:02:31 +0200] [Job 3] The printer is unreachable at this time.
W [13/Jul/2023:03:03:02 +0200] [Job 3] The printer is unreachable at this time.
`
```

After some small adjustments (changing DefaultAuthType to None and installing the aforementioned drivers), this is the only errors I am left with:

```
==> /var/log/cups/error_log <==
W [13/Jul/2023:04:33:22 +0200] [Job 6] The printer is unreachable at this time.
W [13/Jul/2023:04:33:57 +0200] [Job 6] The printer is unreachable at this time.
W [13/Jul/2023:04:34:35 +0200] [Job 6] The printer is unreachable at this time.
W [13/Jul/2023:04:35:06 +0200] [Job 6] The printer is unreachable at this time.
W [13/Jul/2023:04:35:38 +0200] [Job 6] The printer is unreachable at this time.
W [13/Jul/2023:04:36:10 +0200] [Job 6] The printer is unreachable at this time.
W [13/Jul/2023:04:36:43 +0200] [Job 6] The printer is unreachable at this time.
W [13/Jul/2023:04:37:18 +0200] [Job 6] The printer is unreachable at this time.
W [13/Jul/2023:04:37:56 +0200] [Job 6] The printer is unreachable at this time.
W [13/Jul/2023:04:38:27 +0200] [Job 6] The printer is unreachable at this time.
```

When I try to print something, the job says 'processing' and it doesn't go through.

lpstat -l gives:

```
XP-225-6                adelaide          1024   do 13 jul 2023 04:30:45 CEST
    Status: The printer is unreachable at this time.
    Alerts: job-printing
    queued for XP-225
```

This is quite frustrating, its such a useless error to me. I haven't been able to find anything I can do to fix this final message either. I hope someone here can help, I would greatly appreciate it.